# Android Studio: can't choose python interpreter with python plugin

Tags: android-studio

I'm running Android Studio 2.3 with the "Pycharm community edition" plugin to allow the code highlighting, linting, and running etc of .py files that happen to be in my Android Studio project folder.

(To be clear, the python scripts only ever runs locally on my machine and I'm certainly not expecting to run any python code on Android. The .py files are utility scripts that just happen to be in the same working directory as the rest of the Android project).

However, when I go to edit configurations I'm unable to select an interpreter that already exists on my machine (The only option is "Project Default"). In IntelliJ (which Android Studio is based off-of) one can go to Project Structure > Add, and add a python SDK.

In Android Studio, going to Project Structure > Add only gives me a choice between Android related modules. How am I supposed to chose my python interpreter with the Android Studio python plugin? Is this a bug? Without getting to chose the interpreter, the code highlighting says it can't find basic modules like "import os" or "import math". Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: There's a bug open with JetBrains that seems to reflect this issue: [Pycharm Community Edition not compatible with Android Studio](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56694/Pycharm-Community-Edition-not-compatible-with-Android-Studio)